# Access EntityManagerFactory in grails

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, grails

How can I access EntityManagerFactory in a grails web application or any other persistence unit?

I could  access it with name by below code if a had a `persistence.xml` config but grails hides most of configurations.

```
 EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence
    .createEntityManagerFactory("my.entity.manager.name");
```

What I have tried so far:
1. automatic DI does not work with `def entityManagerFactory`.
2. I listed all the beans from ctx in grails shell but nothing like entity manager was found.

OR is their a way I can create `persistence.xml` or somehow override default persistence configuration.

Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Were you ever able to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need an `EntityManager`?

Grails/Gorm accesses hibernate through [Session](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html) and [SessionFactory](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html) instead of using the JPA specification.

You can inject the `sessionFactory` bean in your grails code using

```
def sessionFactory
```